# jQuery ul, nested list filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jquery and learning via the official documentation. While reading I had html codes similar like this...

```
   <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
          <ul class="level-3">
             <li class="item-1">1</li>
             <li class="item-2">2</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
   </ul>
```

I wanted to set backgroundColor/border that are direct child of the "ul.level-2" ...except the child who has nested "ul"  ...I successfully acquired it via...

```
   $("ul.level-2").children("li").each(function(){
       var theChild = $(this).children("ul").length;
       if(!theChild){
           $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
       };
   });
```

Now my question is jquery is for short code writing... how I can use jquery selector/filter to short this code... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$("ul.level-2 > li:not(:has(ul))").each(function(){
$(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
})
```

and shortest one

```
  $("ul.level-2 > li:not(:has(ul))").css("backgroundColor", "red");
```